# Ошибка: fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Здравствуйте! Нашла прототип нужной мне программы в интернете. Пытаюсь это в 2010 студии перенести. Создаю пустой проект, консольное приложение.
Код вот

```
#include <iostream.h>

class Number;

class Memento
{
public:
  Memento(int val) {
    _state = val;
  }
private:
  friend class Number;
  int _state;
};

class Number
{
public:
  Number(int value) {
    _value = value;
  }

  void dubble() {
    _value = 2 * _value;
  }

  void half() {
    _value = _value / 2;
  }

  int getValue() {
    return _value;
  }

  Memento *createMemento() {
    return new Memento(_value);
  }

  void reinstateMemento(Memento *mem) {
    _value = mem->_state;
  }
private:
  int _value;
};

class Command
{
public:
  typedef void(Number:: *Action)();
  Command(Number *receiver, Action action) {
    _receiver = receiver;
    _action = action;
  }

  virtual void execute() {
    _mementoList[_numCommands] = _receiver->createMemento();
    _commandList[_numCommands] = this;
    if (_numCommands > _highWater)
      _highWater = _numCommands;
    _numCommands++;
    (_receiver-> *_action)();
  }

  static void undo() {
    if (_numCommands == 0) {
      cout << "*** Attempt to run off the end!! ***" << endl;
      return ;
    }
    _commandList[_numCommands - 1]->_receiver->reinstateMemento (_mementoList[_numCommands - 1]);
    _numCommands--;
  }

  void static redo() {
    if (_numCommands > _highWater) {
      cout << "*** Attempt to run off the end!! ***" << endl;
      return ;
    }
    (_commandList[_numCommands]->_receiver->*(_commandList[_numCommands]
      ->_action))();
    _numCommands++;
  }
protected:
  Number *_receiver;
  Action _action;
  static Command *_commandList[20];
  static Memento *_mementoList[20];
  static int _numCommands;
  static int _highWater;
};

Command *Command::_commandList[];
Memento *Command::_mementoList[];
int Command::_numCommands = 0;
int Command::_highWater = 0;

int main() {
  int i;
  cout << "Integer: ";
  cin >> i;
  Number *object = new Number(i);

  Command *commands[3];
  commands[1] = new Command(object, &Number::dubble);
  commands[2] = new Command(object, &Number::half);

  cout << "Exit[0], Double[1], Half[2], Undo[3], Redo[4]: ";
  cin >> i;

  while (i) {
    if (i == 3)
      Command::undo();
    else if (i == 4)
      Command::redo();
    else
      commands[i]->execute();
    cout << "   " << object->getValue() << endl;
    cout << "Exit[0], Double[1], Half[2], Undo[3], Redo[4]: ";
    cin >> i;
  }
}
```

Пишет ошибку

```
>1.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: iostream.h: No such file or directory
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: гугл советует писать 


    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;


 но это не работает..

Comment: ЭТО НЕ РАБОТАЕТ! Мой мозг!

Круто, а вы не думали, что в коде было несколько проблем, и когда вы исправили первую, проявилась вторая?

---
Кстати, гугл всё правильно советует.

Comment: хм..все не так ужасно, как мне подумалось...тогда попробуйте добваить еще #include "stdafx.h"

Comment: подскажите что за проблема в коде

Comment: Эээ... Вы меня пригласите в гости, чтобы я увидел сообщение об ошибке, или напишете его сами?

Comment: заменить iostream.h на iostream, сразу за этой строкой добавить `using namespace std;`. строку `_receiver-> *_action` заменить на `_receiver->*_action` (удалить пробел).

Comment: помогло хотя бы?

Comment: да,все нормально

Comment: Эээ, народ, за что закрываете???

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
```